# Rails rendering partial from inside a submodule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a submodule that sits in the root directory within my rails application. It's effectively another rails app, with modules that i wish to keep external so they can be used in other applications I build. I'm currently trying to render a partial within the submodules's views folder, the class that is actually trying to do the rendering is also within the submodule, however the call to said class is in a view within the main rails application.

It seems to throw an undefined method error, that it does not understand the "render" method, even though the suggestion is a "_renderers" method which i'm under the impression is also a rails method. So by that logic I'm assuming that it does understand rails methods, it just doesn't like render.

Is it not possible to call the render method from within a submodule, or is there some sort of require issue that i need to solve in order use render?

Module calling render (root/submodule_name/app/controllers/submodule_name/application_controller.rb):

```
require 'ostruct'

module Pugin
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    def self.get_component(component_name, model = nil)
        if model.is_a?(Hash)
            model = OpenStruct.new(model)
            render :partial => "layouts/pugin/#{component_name}", locals: {object: model}
        else
            render :partial => "layouts/pugin/#{component_name}", locals: {object: model}
        end
    end

  end
end
```

View calling module (root/app/views/people/show.html.slim):

```
= PUGIN.get_component('modules/profile-card', @person)
```

N.B PUGIN is a constant that resolves to Module::Class

Comment: be sure that your partial is named as the convention  "_<partial-name>"

Comment: Yeah the partials are all named correctly, for the example above, the partial is "_profile-card.html.slim"